# Scroll to next element in circular mode

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use next and prev arrows to switch images and I use next() to fade next image, but when there are no images left it obviously won't recycle from the first image. How to make this code work and let the next button go to first image after reaching the end of images element with that class.

My code:

```
$('.nextImage').live('click',function(){
    $('.main-image .zoom:visible').fadeOut(800);
    $('.main-image .zoom:visible').next().fadeIn(800);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just test if there is a next element, and if not, return to the beginning.

```
$('.nextImage').on('click',function(){  // .live() is deprecated
    var $img = $('.main-image .zoom:visible').last(),  // just want one
        $next = $img.next();
    if (0==$next.length) {
       $next = $img.siblings().first();
    }
    $img.fadeOut(800);
    $next.fadeIn(800);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tAChA/

Comment: +1 just for the [Yoda condition](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html) !

Comment: I have no idea why when it reach the end it does not fade to first item, instead it goes to previous item before last item then fade back to last item. :(

Comment: Update it happens when I click too fast on the item, do you think it is related to the fadeOut, fadeIn needing to complete transition?

Comment: Answer updated. If you click too fast, more than one image is `:visible` -- solve this by adding `.last()` to reduce the set of matches to one. Alternatively, you can add code to disable the `click` handler until the transition is complete.